# SharePoint Calculated Column

Tags: calculated-column-formula

Im no expert but I seem to be struggling with this.

I have a calculated column field called [Review Days] for which I hope to enter an amount of days that a document will need reviewing. 1 year will equal 365 days, 2 years, 720 days etc.

I can get this to work no problem.. the problems is, if [Review Days] is blank then I want to default this field value, [Next Review Date] equals [modified] + 1825 days or 5 years.

I kinda see something like this:

```
=IF(  ISBLANK([Review Days])  ,  ""  ,  Modified+1825  ,  [Modified]+[Review Days]  )
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: An IF function has True/False results, you have 3 results

Comment: =IF(Review days="";[Modified]+1825,[Modified]+[Review Days])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Review Days]),Modified+1825,Modified+[Review Days])
```

Ensure that the calculated column is of Date type.

[image]

More information on [ISBLANK](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IS-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB):

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
=IF(Review days="";[Modified]+1825,[Modified]+[Review Days])
```